# Retrieving varbinary image in sql server when it not null

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, varbinarymax

I'm trying to retrieve an image stored as a `varbinary(max)` column from my SQL Server 2008 database. When the image column is not equal to `NULL` then I get the image from the database. Below is the code I use to retrieve my image. Do help me take a look on my code, I not sure where I did wrongly. Thanks!

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string strQuery = "select profilepicture from MemberAccount where nric='"+ Session["nric"] +"' and profilepicture IS NOT NULL";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);
    if (dt != null)
    {
       download(dt);
    }
}

private DataTable GetData(SqlCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = localhost; Initial Catalog = MajorProject; Integrated Security= SSPI");
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();
        sda.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}

private void download(DataTable dt)
{
    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["profilepicture"];
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
}
```

Line:

```
Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["profilepicture"];
```

Error:

> There is no row at position 0.

Comment: learn how to use CommandParameters and what is the value in Session["nric"].? What happens if you execute the query directly in SSMS with that value?

Comment: You can add an extra safeguard: if (dt != null && dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count>0)

Comment: Somewhat off-topic, but still...... @Rene: if dt is not null, dt.Rows will never be null as this is initialized in the constructor of DataTable, so you can shorten your code to (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)

Comment: @ManishDalal That is true. I didn't check that implementation detail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defensive database programming 101: you need to ***check*** whether you get data or not! You cannot convert nothing to an image... and you cannot just blindly assume you'll get data. ALWAYS check!

```
private void download(DataTable dt)
{
    // check if you have any rows at all 
    // no rows -> no data to convert!
    if(dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
       return;

    // check if your row #0 even contains data -> if not, you can't do anything!
    if(data.Rows[0].IsNull("profilepicture"))
       return;

    Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["profilepicture"];
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Charset = "";
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.End();
}
```